# Python Pandas Data Frame - how to Shorten the Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 1m entries. The python program is searching for specific entries and bubbling those up to the top of the frame. I then want to write the frame containing only the entries of interest to a csv file.  Is there a way to shorten the frame so that it is now only a frame containing the entries of interest instead of remaining 1m lines long? Example - say 100 entries are of interest. They are now the first 100 entries of the frame - is there a way to shorten the resulting frame so that it is only 100 entries long instead of 1m?

To Questions - these entries are identical to the original data in width. As far as knowing how many there are - it isn't known how many are good before the program runs but the program will count the entries of interest so I will know how entries there are - so I will know if there are 100 or 125, etc.

Comment: you can slice the dataframe by using `.isin` on your areas of interest, or if you want the top 100 rows you could do `df1 = df.head(100)` or `df1  = df.iloc[:100]`

Comment: How are the "specific entries" stored - i.e., how do you know what/where they are?

Answer (score 1):

You can try **indexing** on the dataframe.

Assume "df" is your dataframe, with a column "value", and I want to find all results larger than 5, I could do the following:

```
indexes_of_interest = (df['value'] > 5)
short_df = df[indexes_of_interest]
```

The first line of the code is the definition of an arbitrary filter (in this case: 'is the value larger than 5). In the second line, I select the records that meet this criterion and save this to a shorter dataframe.

The "short_df" is now a dataframe that *only* contains the records of interest.